# How to show confirm box before removing tag from select2

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-select2

How to show confirm box before removing a tag from select2? I have a text box where I have two options selected on removing of any of them I want to display a warning message. Can anyone help me in this?
In HTML I have element as

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-3 control-label required">Select Type</label>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <select id="typeselect" class="form-control" name="crm" required>
            <option value='0'>Select Type</option>
            <option value='1'>Type1</option>
            <option value='2'>Type2</option>
        </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And in the js file

```
$("#typeselect").select2({
        placeholder: 'Select Type'
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Its a good idea to include a snippet or some relevant code

Comment: post your code ?

Comment: Have you made any code that removes an option, or do you "hope" we will create that also?=

Comment: @sunshine Have you checked my below answer?? Is it works?

Comment: @sunshine is the problem fixed or do you still have a problem with the code?

Comment: @sunshine Below 2 answers is help you or not? Please leave a comment. If yes, then please accept it and give upvote as well. If not, let we know what error you get?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function deleteItem() {
   if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
     $("#type option:selected").remove();
   }
   return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='type'>
<option value='1'>Type1</option>
<option value='2'>Type2</option>
</select>
<button onclick='deleteItem()'>Remove</button>
```

Add `onClick` event on `option` tag like:

```
<select id='type'>
    <option value='1'>Type1</option>
    <option value='2'>Type2</option>
</select>
<button onclick='deleteItem()'>Remove</button>
```

Then You need to add `confirm()` to your `deleteItem();` like this:

```
function deleteItem() {
   if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
     $("#type option:selected").remove();
   }
   return false;
}
```

Please try this and let me know if this solved your issue!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is 2 ways of doing it:

1. Use a simple [Confirm](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp), like `if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {// your deletion code}`
2. Use [Jquery-UI - Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation) see example below

```js
$("#typeselect").select2({
  placeholder: 'Select Type'
});

$("#remove").click(function() {
  var selectedval = $("#typeselect option:selected").val();
  if (selectedval > 0) {
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: "auto",
      width: 400,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $("#typeselect option:selected").remove();
          $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
        }
      }
    });
  }
})
```

```css
#dialog-confirm {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="name" class="col-lg-3 control-label required">Select Type</label>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <select id="typeselect" class="form-control" name="crm" required>
            <option value='0'>Select Type</option>
            <option value='1'>Type1</option>
            <option value='2'>Type2</option>
        </select>
    <button id="remove">Remove selected value</button>
    <div id="dialog-confirm" title="Delete option">
      <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:12px 12px 20px 0;"></span>Do you wish to delete this option?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```